# How to stub out and test ssh commands

Tags: python, testing, ssh, end-to-end

I am a developer on a system that sends out ssh commands, roughly in the format 'ssh -o 'BatchMode yes' hostname command'. I am working on our end to end testing and am tasked with mocking out the remote servers during testing. I need to prevent the ssh command running on the remote server, and instead capture the ssh command in some way, check it matches what I expect for that test and return a response specified specifically for that test to control the test flow. My system is in python and runs in RHEL7 docker containers, a solution that can be created within those technologies would be preferable. Does anyone have any suggestions of the best way to do this?

I have considered alias'ing ssh but i don't think that's ideal as i'm restricting the scope of the test more than if the ssh command is carried out. My best idea is creating a mock ssh server that captures the command but i have yet to find the technology to easily capture a non-interactive ssh command and respond.

Comment: "I am looking to improve our automated end-to-end testing" => This is too broad. Please provide more context on what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: Are the `ssh` options complicated, so that you need the real program to parse them?  If not, I don’t see why you need to mock so as to test `ssh` itself.

Comment: Not too complicated, typically they just run a command and wait for the response, but normally the command can take a while, and I want a instant response for testing and not to use the actually remote host. What is the alternative to mocking them out?